# Is there a way to create a Pandas dataframe where the values map to an index/row pair?

Tags: python, pandas

I was struggling with how to word the question, so I will provide an example of what I am trying to do below. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     ID     CODE    COST
0   60086   V2401   105.38
1   60142   V2500   221.58
2   60086   V2500   105.38
3   60134   V2750   35
4   60134   V2020   0
```

I am trying to create a dataframe that has the ID as rows, the CODE as columns, and the COST as values since the cost for the same code is different per ID. How can I do this in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a classic "long to wide" problem, and there are several ways to do it. You can try [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), for example:

```
df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='CODE', values='COST')
```

(assuming that the dataframe is `df`.)